# How to copy elements to second array without the uppercase characters?

Tags: java, for-loop, arrays

I need to copy the elements of the one array to another array  **delete the upper case and just copy the lower case**. I would appreciate assistance.

I've used the `System.arraycopy()` and the output is the sum of upper case:

> 5 [a, B, c, R, n, k, W, v, t, G, L]

This is my code

```
package question4;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CharArray {



    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] array = new char[]{'a','B','c','R','n','k','W','v','t','G','L',};
        char[] newarray = new char[array.length];

        int n = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i ++){
         if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i])){
             n++;
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, newarray, 0, array.length); 

         }
        }
        System.out.println("the sum of uperCase is : " + n);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newarray));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each char has an ASCII representation. You cen get it by simply casting a char to an int: `int aCode = (int) 'a';` will set the value of aCode to 97. Lower case chars start at code 97-122, upper case chars are all below 97.

I guess this is a kind of homework so I guess you are not allowed to use things like `ArrayList` which have variable sizes. So you will also have to calculate the amount of lower case chars in your array.

```
int lowerCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ((int) array[i] >= 97 && (int) array[i] <= 122) lowerCount++;
}
```

Now let's declare a new char array with the calculated size:

```
char[] newArray = new char[lowerCount];
```

Now you can start to copy the lower case chars to the new array:

```
int newIndex = 0;

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if ((int) array[i] >= 97 && (int) array[i] <= 122) {
        newArray[newIndex] = array[i];
        newIndex++;
    }
}

System.out.println("The lower case chars are:" + Arrays.toString(newArray) + "; There are " newArray.length + " of them.);
System.out.println((array.length-newArray.length) + " capital chars werde removed.")
```

You need newIndex to memorize how many chars you've already copied to the new array - means at which index to store the next found lower case char.

Comment: Each char has a Unicode representation, I would suggest

Comment: Each char has a UC representation, yes. But parsing a char into an int will give you the ascii code, wouldn't it?

Comment: The point I'm making is that Unicode character sets go way beyond the 7-bit ASCII set and the extended character sets will have upper/lower case characters beyond this. I would rather use the Character upper/lower case methods to handle these scenarios.

Comment: We are talking about the primitive type char, not about Character, right?

Comment: I don't think it matters. The doc says "The Character class wraps a value of the primitive type char in an object. An object of type Character contains a single field whose type is char. In addition, this class provides several methods for determining a character's category (lowercase letter, digit, etc.) and for converting characters from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa."

Comment: OK, you're right. But casting a char into an int will still give you the ASCII representation. A char might have also a representation in morse code but casting it into an int will give you the ASCII code, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy only lowercase, then since you don't know how many array elements are upper or lower case in advance, I would rather copy into a dynamically sized collection (e.g. an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) and then convert to an array upon completion e.g.

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (Character c : array) {
   if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
      chars.add(c);
   }
}
Character[] lowerCase = chars.toArray(new Character[0]);
```

It's a bit simpler than worrying about `System.arrayCopy()` (which I'd rather use for bulk copies than just copying individual elements) and all the offsets you're maintaining.

Note the resultant array is the size of the number of lowercase elements it's been populated with (as opposed to the statically sized array defined in advance, as per the above)

Note also it's not clear what you'd want to happen if you have a non-alphabetical character in the original array. If that occurs you may want a more robust character check.

Comment: Whoops. Lowercase rather than uppercase. Corrected. IS that the reason for the downvote ?

Comment: He wants to put all letters into the new array and convert existing uppercase to lowercase. Not move the uppercase/lowercase into the second array exclusively.

Comment: It's not clear to me, especially given the title *How to copy elements to second array without the uppercase characters?*

Comment: I think the first line of his question clears it up: "I need to copy the elements of the one array to another array and convert upper case to lower case."

Comment: this solution will copy the upercase only ... what i want is to copy the hall elements without the upercase so its the reverse of your answer ... thank you for your help

Comment: @ leigero no sir i want to delete the uperCase and just copy the lower case to the new array

Comment: I suppose this is a kind of a homework for beginners so I don't think that the usage of ArrayList is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Take temp array to store the values and then copy those values in your newArray according to length of capital letters.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  char[] array = new char[]{'a','B','c','R','n','k','W','v','t','G','L',};
  char[] temp = new char[array.length];

  int cnt = 0;
  int n = 0;

  for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i ++){
    if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i])){
        n++;
        temp[cnt++]=array[i];  // put your values in temp array
    }
  }

 System.out.println("the sum of uperCase is : " + n);

    char[] newarray = new char[cnt]; // cnt giving no of capital letters
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, newarray, 0, cnt); // copy temp array to new array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newarray));
  }
```

Output

```
the sum of uperCase is : 5
[B, R, W, G, L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently your code copies all the values of `array` into `newarray` every time there is an upper case character.

To achieve what you want, try this:

```
int n = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i ++){
    if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i])){
       n++;
    }
}

char[] newarray = new char[array.lenght - n];
int index = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < array.lenght;i++){
   if(Character.isLowerCase(array[i])){
       newarray[index++] = array[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use isUpperCase and array.length-n instead isLowerCase and n as the new size?

Comment: @MichaelS because he also wants to count the total number of uppercase characters. That was specified in his question before he edited it.

Comment: Makes sense. On the other hand the number of capital chars is `array.length-newarray.length`. But you're right, it's not important where you do the subtraction.